# Как сохранить данные из массива в текстовый файл

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сохранить из "ArrayList myPoints" данные в текстовый файл? Сейчас у меня в примере, если сохраняется большой объем данных(500 строк), и в это время резко выйти из программы, то данные в файле обрезаются(иногда не успевают записаться как надо) и потом программа не работает..
Надо как-то ускорить процесс записи, или перестраховаться, чтобы все данные записались в файл..
Сейчас сделано вот так:

```
ArrayList<String[]> myPoints = new ArrayList();

....

public void mySavePoints(final String file_name) {
    final String[] FileStrTxt = {""};
    // поток
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

    try {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(new File(file_name));
        while (scnr.hasNext()) {
            FileStrTxt[0] = FileStrTxt[0] + scnr.next();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    try {
        Formatter fmr = new Formatter(file_name);
        Iterator itr = myPoints.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            String[] P = (String[]) itr.next();
            P[1] = P[1].replace("﹀", "^"); 
            P[5] = P[5].replace("﹀", "^");
            P[6] = P[6].replace("﹀", "^");
            P[7] = P[7].replace("﹀", "^");
            P[8] = P[8].replace("﹀", "^");
            P[9] = P[9].replace("﹀", "^");
            P[10] = P[10].replace("﹀", "^");
            fmr.format("%s﹀%s﹀%s﹀%s﹀%s﹀%s﹀%s﹀%s﹀%s﹀%s﹀%s\n",
                    new Object[]{P[0], P[1], P[2], P[3], P[4], P[5], P[6], P[7], P[8], P[9], P[10]});
        }
        fmr.close();
    } catch (Exception e1) {

    }

     //конец потока
        }
    };
    thread.start();

}
```

Comment: Вероятно, вам стоит посмотреть в сторону сервисов https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services?hl=ru